# How to calculate total sum of checkbox values depend on quantity in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following table

```
<table>
<tr style="background-color: silver;">
    <th>Check it</th>
    <th>Estimate item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Cost</th>               
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="450" /></td>
   <td>Remove Tile</td>
   <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
   <td>$450</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="550" /></td>
   <td>Remove Tub</td>
   <td><input type="text" value="1"></td>
   <td>$550</td>
</tr>
```

`<p>Calculated Price: $<input type="text" name="price" id="price" disabled /></p>`

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYLuq.png)
I found how to calculate the sum of checkboxes values:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"]')
            $inputs.on('change', function () {
                var sum = 0;
                $inputs.each(function() {
                   if(this.checked)
                       sum += parseInt(this.value);
                });
                $("#price").val(sum);
            });
        });
</script>
```

The question is: 
If user will update the quantity in textbox, i need to update the total.
I want it to work in two ways: quantity changed before or after checkbox has been checked.

So the value in "Cost" column is equal to checkbox value. I do not want to modify "Cost" column. I need total to be shown at the bottom of the table in "textbox with id="price" textbox.

Case:
User checked the first checkbox #price should be updated with 450. 
User checked the second checkbox #price should benow 1000.
User changed the quantity to 2 in the row with the first checkbox.Now #price should be updated to 1450

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yosiharepi/edit?html,js,console,output this?

Comment: or ... https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/dom/checkbox-events.php  all you need to do is hit a search engine to get this info... along with examples.

Comment: That is not what I want. I have a checkbox with value 450 and textbox(quantity) value =1. The total price will be 450. if I will check the second checkbox with value 50, and textbox(quantity) will be = 1. The total will be = 500. And now if I will change the quantity for checkbox number 1 to quantity 2. The total should be 950. This is an estimate application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you should loop through the table body's row for that use the code as

```
 $('table tbody tr').each(function() 
 {
     //do something
 });
```

and then find the checkbox in that row. You can check if the check box is checked by using `$tr.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')` this code. It will find a check box in the row and it will check whether it is checked or not.

`var $columns = $tr.find('td').next('td').next('td');` This code is used to retrieve the column Quantity.

We call the function `calculateSum()` to calculate the sum coast of checked rows in both textbox change event and checkbox change event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

function calculateSum(){
 var sumTotal=0;
    $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
      var $tr = $(this);

      if ($tr.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
          
        var $columns = $tr.find('td').next('td').next('td');
         
         var $Qnty=parseInt($tr.find('input[type="text"]').val());
 var $Cost=parseInt($columns.next('td').html().split('$')[1]);
         sumTotal+=$Qnty*$Cost;
      }
    });

       $("#price").val(sumTotal);
       
}

  $('#sum').on('click', function() {
     
    calculateSum();
  });

  $("input[type='text']").keyup(function() {
     calculateSum();

  });
  
   $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
     calculateSum();

  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sum" type="button">Calculate</button><br/>

<table>
  <tr style="background-color: silver;">
    <th>Check it</th>
    <th>Estimate item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chck" value="450" /></td>
    <td>Remove Tile</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="qnty" value="1"></td>
    <td>$450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chck" value="550" /></td>
    <td>Remove Tub</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="qnty" value="1"></td>
    <td>$550</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  
  <p>Calculated Price: $<input type="text" name="price" id="price" disabled /></p>
```

Comment: Is this is the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Please see, I have updated the post.

Comment: @AnatolyPerevera I also edited my answer. Just go through that and kindly update you feedback.

Comment: This is Awesome JINO!!! Could you please add one more function: When quantity changed to update the textbox "#price" value. I appreciate that!!!

Comment: @AnatolyPerevera Yeah that's done. just changed the text box event to keypres. Now it's working. Just go through that and kindly give your feedback to know is this is what you want?.

Comment: @AnatolyPerevera If this answer is useful for you accept it. so that it will be useful for others.

Comment: I have clicked on "This answer is useful" arrow, but nothing happened.

Comment: Just click on that tick. you can't upvote now because your reputation is low. so instead of that just accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark shown below the down arrow.

Comment: Done! Sorry it's my first post here

Comment: Yeah, that i can understand and that's why i told you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="serve" id="service"> 

<form action="" id="roomform" onsubmit="return false">
<div class="order">
<fieldset>
<legend>Tell us where to clean:</legend>
<p>
<input value="30" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="sum" name="myCheck" oninput="x.value=parseInt(bedroom.value)*30.00"/>
<label for="sleeping" class="contain">Bedrooms (P30/room) </label> 
<input type="number" id="a" class="room" value="1" min="1" max="20" onchange="calculateTotal()"/>
Total: P <span id="costPrice"> </span
</p>
<p>
<input value="20" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="sum" name="myCheck1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
<label for="sitting" class="contain">Sitting room (P20/room)</label> 
<input type="number" class="room" id="a" value="1" min="1" max="20" />
Total: P <output type="number" ></output> 
</p>
<p>
 <input value="20" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="sum" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
 <label class="contain">Dining room (P20/room)</label> 
 <input type="number" class="room" id="a" value="1" min="1" max="20" />
 Total: P <output type="number" ></output>    
 </p>

 <p>
 Extra services:</p>
 <p>
 <input value="15" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="sum" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
  <label class="contain">Carpet Cleaning (P 15/room)</label> 
  <input type="number" class="room" id="a" value="0" min="0" max="20" />
Total: P <output type="number" ></output>    
</p>
 <p>
 <input value="3" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="sum"   onclick="calculateTotal()" />
 <label class="contain">Window Cleaning (P 3/room)</label> 
<input type="number" class="room" id="a" value="0" min="0" max="20" />
Total: P <output type="number" ></output> 
</p>
<div class="grandPrice" >
 Grand Total Price: P<span id="grandTotal">0</span>
 </div>
 </fieldset>    
 </div>
  </form>
 <script>
 // When a checkbox is clicked
 /*$('#order input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
// Get user input and set initial variable for the total
inputBox = parseInt($('#a').val());
bedroomPrices = 0;

// If it's checked, add the current value to total

    if($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        thisValue = parseInt($(this).val());
        bedroomPrices = bedroomPrices + thisValue;
    }

// Output the total checkbox value multipled against user input
$('#costPrice').html(bedroomPrices * inputBox);    
 });*/

 var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
 inputBox = document.getElementById('a'),
    GrandTotal  = document.getElementById('grandTotal');

 //"(this.checked ? 1 : -1);" this sees if checkbox is checked or unchecked   by adding or subtracting it (1 :-1)
//make sure that each checkbox total is added if its checked
for (var i=0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    checkbox[i].onchange = function() {

        var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);

        grandTotal.innerHTML = parseFloat(grandTotal.innerHTML) + add

    }
}
```

```
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please add a meaningful problem description here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="indent_list">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>rate</th>
                <th>quantity</th>
                <th>coltotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <body>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="val" class="rate" value="10"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="val" class="quantity" value="1"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="val" class="coltolal" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="val" class="rate" value="10"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="val" class="quantity" value="2"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="val" class="coltolal" value=""></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="val" class="rate" value="10"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="val" class="quantity" value="2"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="val" class="coltolal" value=""></td>

            </tr>
        </body>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th class="rateRow"></th>
                <th class="quantityRow"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" class="totalRow"></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

> button

<input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-info checkbox" onclick="calculateCheck()">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate">

> script

<script>
    function calculateCheck() {
        var check = $('.checkbox').prop('checked');
        if (check) {
            calculate()
        } else {
            $('.rateRow').text('');
            $('.quantityRow').text('');
            $('.totalRow').text('');
        }
    }
    function calculate() {
        var rateRow = '';
        var quantityRow = '';
        var totalRow = '';
        var rate = 0;
        var quantity = 0;
        var total = 0;

        // alert(quantitycol);
        $('tbody tr').each(function () {
            var ratecol = $('td .rate', this).val();
            var quantitycol = $('td .quantity', this).val();
            var coltotal = ratecol * quantitycol;
            $('td .coltolal', this).val(coltotal);
            // alert(a);
            rate += +$('td .rate', this).val();
            quantity += +$('td .quantity', this).val();
            total = rate * quantity;
           
        });
        rateRow += rate;
        quantityRow += quantity;
        totalRow = total;

        $('.rateRow').text(rateRow);
        $('.quantityRow').text(quantityRow);
        $('.totalRow').text(totalRow);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: sum value with checkbox or button

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain anything. Please check this: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)